# Azure option to receive SOAP requests

Tags: azure, soap, windows-services

We currently have a solution where we receive SOAP requests on a url, the ASP.Net page that services this url then posts that request to a database, this is then picked up from a windows service and 'processed'.

The windows service does most of the work ensuring that the XML within the SOAP request passes various validations and is passed on to the next service.

My question is, we are looking to modernise this solution so that we make it faster, handle failure of infrastructure better and provide it with more scalability as we are looking to expand its use into the US. We think that we may be able to use Azure services to help us with this, but to be honest we don't have the knowledge in-house to know what would be best for us to use.

Could anyone point us in the right direction so that we could then concentrate our investigations. Things have moved on a lot from when we first wrote this solution and we're sure there is more scope out there now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on what i understood seems like you are looking for a reliable/scalable messaging platform and a service to process the messages that are put on the messaging system.

A lot of business requirements knowledge is needed here to advice a proper package but as a log shot I can suggest you this:

Post your messages to Azure Service Bus and then implement an Azure Web Job that picks up posted messages on the bus and then pass it to the next service or do the processing and put it back on the Bus again.

So based on that your technologies that you have to go take a look are:

1.Azure Service Bus

2.Azure Web Jobs

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, yes, a messaging platform is what we are looking for, we have hand cranked our own messaging system so far, which works great, but is limiting us slightly as we look to expand our client base. I have begun looking into the Azure Service bus, but unfortunately we are dealing with large messages as we stream documents within the messages, so the message size limit is no good for us.

Comment: right, If you are trying to do streaming you should look at Azure Media Services or Azure Blob Storage...